# how to use stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet in NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nscharacterset

I have a string  which gives the Date (below)

```
NSString*str1=[objDict objectForKey:@"date"];

 NSLog(@" str values2%@",str1); --> 04-Jan-13
```

Now Problem is I need to Trim the`"-13"` from here .I know about `NSDateFormatter` to format date.but I can't do that here.I need to trim that

For that I am using:-

```
 NSCharacterSet *charc=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-13"];

 [str1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charc];
```

But this does not work.this does not trim...how to do that..help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this does not work.this does not trim...

It does trim, but since `NSString` is *immutable*, the trimmed string is thrown away, because you do not assign it to anything.

This would work **(but do not do it like that!)**

```
str1 = [str1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charc];
```

What you do is not trimming, it's taking a substring. `NSString` provides a much better method for that:

```
str1 = [str1 substringToIndex:6]; // Take the initial 6 characters
```

Comment: @Christien No, it does not :( At least, it does not *always* work: try `13-jan-13` to see why.

Comment: @Christien No, it does not work, because the order of characters in `NSCharacterSet` does not matter. Try it - it wouldn't work even with `31-jan-13`.

Comment: ya thanks for sharing this ..thanks.. now using substringToIndex

Comment: and one more thing..I need to open my app with Facebook login..which one I should use..I tried FBConnect but its been expired..then I tried  Facebook SDK but it takes me to safari to open ..isnt it anything like FBConnect??

Comment: @Christien I think you should ask this in a separate question, to get attention of someone who knows about FB (I do not even have an account there).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why not use an NSDateFormatter but here's a very specific way to approach this (very bad coding practice in my opinion):

```
NSString *theDate = str1;
NSArray *components = [theDate componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *trimmedDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",[components objectAtIndex:0],[components objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: thanks man! this gives me the correct one.didnt get the logic...stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@"

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
NSString *trimmed = [textStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

or this:

```
NSString *trimmed = [textStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-13"];
```

Answer (score 3):

what you have done is correct. Only thing is `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` returns `NSString`. So you need to assign this value to `NSString`, like

```
str1 = [str1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charc];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're sure you have your string always formatted like "NN-CCC-NN" you can just trim the first 6 chars:

```
NSString* stringToTrim = @"04-Jan-13";
NSString* trimmedString =  [stringToTrim substringToIndex:6];
NSLog(@"trimmedString: %@", trimmedString); // -> trimmedString: 04-Jan
```